# dotnet 5 MVC 404 error when I post to action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have a page that is supposed to submit data for a patient evaluation.  The page to submit the evaluation comes up fine.  It is based on a ViewModel.  Here is the ViewModel:

```
public class SPEPatientEvalVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ApptId { get; set; }
        public int ActivityID { get; set; }
        public int VendorID { get; set; }
        public int PatientID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="A selection is required.")]
        public int OverallRating { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A selection is required.")]
        public int AppearProfessComp { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A selection is required.")]
        public int EffGatheredInfo { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A selection is required.")]
        public int ListenActively { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A selection is required.")]
        public int EstabPersRapport { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A selection is required.")]
        public int AppropExploreMyFeelings { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A selection is required.")]
        public int AddressedMyFeelings { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A selection is required.")]
        public int MetMyNeeds { get; set; }
        public string PatientComments { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public DateTime DateSubmitted { get; set; }
    }
```

This is mapped and reverse mapped to the model using IMapper.

Anyway this is my controller code:

```
[HttpGet("[controller]/[action]/{IDAppt}/{ActivityID}/{VendorID}/{PatientID}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddSPEPatientEval(int IDAppt, int ActivityID, int VendorID, int PatientID)
{
    var patientChoice = GetPatientChoiceList();
    patientChoice[0].Selected = true;
    ViewBag.PatientChoice = patientChoice;

    var evalParams = await _speRepo.GetOpenPatientEval(IDAppt);

    ViewBag.Patient = evalParams.SPEPatient;

    var speEval = new SPEPatientEvalVM
    {
        ApptId = IDAppt,
        ActivityID = ActivityID,
        VendorID = VendorID,
        PatientID = PatientID
    };

    return View(speEval);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddSPEPatientEval(SPEPatientEvalVM model)
{
    var patientChoice = GetPatientChoiceList();
    patientChoice[0].Selected = true;
    ViewBag.PatientChoice = patientChoice;

    model.DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var spePatientEval = _mapper.Map<SPEPatientEval>(model);

        var success = await _speRepo.AddSPEPatientEval(spePatientEval);
        if (!success)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

This is all for the form AddSPEPatientEval.cshtml

```
@model SPEPatientEvalVM

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AddSPEPatientEval";
}

<div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
    <h1 class="text-center">Patient SPE Evaluation</h1>
    <hr />
</div>

<div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form asp-controller="SPE" asp-action="AddSPEPatientEval" method="post">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="ApptId" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="ActivityID" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="VendorID" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="PatientID" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="DateSubmitted" value="@String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)" />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="OverallRating" class="control-label">As @ViewBag.Patient, rate your overall level of satisfaction with this encounter.</label>
                            <select asp-for="OverallRating" class="form-control"
                                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.PatientChoice, "Value", "Text"))"></select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="OverallRating" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="AppearProfessComp" class="control-label">Appeared professional competent - seemed to know what s/he was
                                doing; inspired my comfidence; appeared to have my interests at heart.
                            </b></label>
                            <select asp-for="AppearProfessComp" class="form-control"
                                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.PatientChoice, "Value", "Text"))"></select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="AppearProfessComp" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="EffGatheredInfo" class="control-label">Effectively gathered information - collected information in a way that
                                seemed organized; began with several open-ended questions and progressed through interview using a balanced ratio of open- 
                                to closed-ended questions; summarized periodically.
                            </label>
                            <select asp-for="EffGatheredInfo" class="form-control"
                                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.PatientChoice, "Value", "Text"))"></select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="EffGatheredInfo" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="ListenActively" class="control-label">Listened actively - paid attention to both my verbal and non-verbal 
                                cues; used facial expressions/body language to express encouragement; avoided interruptions; asked questions to make sure 
                                s/he understood what I said.
                            </label>
                            <select asp-for="ListenActively" class="form-control"
                                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.PatientChoice, "Value", "Text"))"></select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="ListenActively" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Established personal rapport - introduced self warmly; verbally/non-verbally showed interest 
                                in me as a person, not just my condition; avoided technical jargon.
                            </label>
                            <select asp-for="EstabPersRapport" class="form-control"
                                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.PatientChoice, "Value", "Text"))"></select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="EstabPersRapport" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="AppropExploreMyFeelings" class="control-label">Appropriately explored my perspective - encouraged me to 
                                identify everything that I needed to say.
                            </label>
                            <select asp-for="AppropExploreMyFeelings" class="form-control"
                                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.PatientChoice, "Value", "Text"))"></select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="AppropExploreMyFeelings" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="AddressedMyFeelings" class="control-label">Addressed my feelings - acknowledged and demonstrated interest in my 
                                expressed and/orunexpressed feelings and experience.
                            </label>
                            <select asp-for="AddressedMyFeelings" class="form-control"
                                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.PatientChoice, "Value", "Text"))"></select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="AddressedMyFeelings" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="MetMyNeeds" class="control-label">Met my needs - worked toward a plan which addressed both the diagnosis and 
                                my concerns about my illness.
                            </label>
                            <select asp-for="MetMyNeeds" class="form-control"
                                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.PatientChoice, "Value", "Text"))"></select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="MetMyNeeds" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="PatientComments" class="control-label"></label>
                            <textarea asp-for="PatientComments" class="form-control"
                                      placeholder="Please add any additional comments you would like to express about this examination."></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 m-auto">
        <div class="text-center">
            <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
    }
```

Once the form is completed and all required fields are entered, if I hit the "Submit" button, I get:

> This localhost page can’t be found
> No webpage was found for the web
> address:
> https://localhost:5001/SPE/AddSPEPatientEval/18659/15129/235/4
> HTTP ERROR 404

What am I missing guys?  I am sure it is something that is in plain site.  I am just have looked at it too long and cannot find what is going on.

What have I tried... I feel like everything.  I have tried adding a route to the HttpPost statement.  I have tried making sure all the model fields are not null.  I do not know what else to try.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `POST` route should match the `GET` route:
`[HttpPost("[controller]/[action]/{IDAppt}/{ActivityID}/{VendorID}/{PatientID}")]`

Comment: So this is strange.  Throughout my application, I have GET actions that are different than the POST.  The post usually accepts a model.  They all work fine.  I added the route to my POST and it still gets the error.  So you are telling me, my post should have the exact same parameters as my GET?  If that is true, why do my others work that the GET requires a int ID and the POST requires a model?

Comment: I am actually going to take that back.  You are correct.  Dufus me put the route on the wrong POST action.  Thanks for your help.  You are great.

Answer (score 1):

Add `[FromRoute]` to the action parameters:

```cs
[HttpGet("[controller]/[action]/{IDAppt}/{ActivityID}/{VendorID}/{PatientID}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddSPEPatientEval([FromRoute]int IDAppt, [FromRoute] int ActivityID, [FromRoute] int VendorID, [FromRoute] int PatientID)
```

You should also change `HttpGet` to `HttpPost`.

Comment: So I ask you the same question I asked hkarask above.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: As you can see my response to hkarask, I put the route on the wrong POST action.  It all works.  Thank you guys for responding.  I very much appreciate it.